# Exchange - exclude emails from being sent to my phone

Tags: exchange

I have a droid and MS Outlook email, which is sent to my phone using Exchange. I'd like email in some folders to NOT be sent to my phone. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you able to add specifically what phone you are using and what version of Android is it running?

Answer (score 0):

if their isn't an option to select a set of folders.
I'm assuming there's something about those folders like big attachments? Or to sensitive to be on a mobile device?
My best advice to you would be to move the folders in question into an archive and set up a rule to automatically sort your mail into that. You'll never see an archive folder on your phone, so job done.
Hope that helps.